# How can I make the button move from the first JTabbedPanel to the next one?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I created a window panel that displays 6 tab panels, and I also made a next and previous buttons to move from tab to tab. My problem is I was only able to make it go from the first tab to the last tab. The buttons skip all the other tabs and I can't seem to find a way to make it go through each tab. This is what I did:

```
next = new JButton("next");
    next.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i <= tabs.getSelectedIndex(); i++)
                    tabs.setSelectedIndex(i);

                }

            });

    previous = new JButton("previous");
    previous.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i >= tabs.getSelectedIndex(); i++)
                    tabs.setSelectedIndex(i);

                }
            });
```

I'm still going to try to figure this out.

Comment: why a `for-loop` ? you need to get the selected tab and + 1 or - 1 and take care for edges, to make it cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to move next/previous you can simply call 
  
`tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()+1)` for next and `-1` for previous.
You will nedd to check is there previous or next tab too.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I was thinking something a lot more complicated.

Comment: Usually the best solution, is the simpliest one :) Take care.

Comment: Indeed. Have a great week! XD

Comment: I just realized I need to make the Index selection loop. For example, if I get to the last button and I hit next, it should jump back to the first one. If I don't get this figure out in three days, I'll ask again. DX